# Error in determine positive\negative number in JAVA

Tags: java

Below snippet is to find the sign(+/-) of number without using `>` or `<` conditional operators basically!

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt(); /**take user input /

    /* stretch user input to either of infinity  */
    n *= Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    /* compare the result now */
    if(n == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
    {
     System.out.println("number is positive ");
    }
    else if (n == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY )
    {
        System.out.println("number is negative" );  
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("could not determine number type!!" );
    }
```

I even added

```
System.out.println("nmbr and negtive infinity is : "+n+" "+Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

**for user input** : -12, it shows :

```
/* Ideally it should be "Infinity -Infinity" according to me */
nmbr and negtive infinity is : 2147483647 -Infinity
```

after doing the multiplication to see the resultant value, but for some reason. i dont get the `nmbr` equal to any infinite value

**2 questions :**

- when taking `int` type input, is it getting promoted to `double` type on multiplication??
- whats wrong with the above logic?? , i am always getting output :

`could not determine number type!!`

Comment: when you multiply by a double, the int becomes a double as well.

Comment: Print `n` and you'll understand why.

Comment: @MarounMaroun : i did, and i know that the value is not going to `infinity` after multiplication and that is what i am not understanding, i added the output in question!!

Comment: The result of multiplying is changed back into int. n is not double an never will be equal to Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY or Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY

Comment: @NoobEditor : Why are you messing with infinity in the first place? What is wrong with Java's Math.signum?

Comment: @SebastianH : m still on learning stage mate,dont know ur way, mind posting it as answer?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an implicit cast in you code.
this:

```
n *= Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
```

is roughly equal to:

```
n = (int) (n * Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

`n` is an `int` in this code snippet, `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` is a `double`, so the result of the calculation is a `double`. After that because you are saving your result in an `int` variable, your result gets `downcasted` to an `int`. `int`s do not have something like infinity, so your double gets `cast`ed to the highest possible Integer: `Integer.MAX_VALUE == 2147483647`. 
It is obvious that this number is not infinity.

If you change your n to double, then your code is working

Comment: +1 : clean explaination, but isnt that in java, smaller range datatypes are automatically promoted to higher (`int` to `double`) when performing opeartions, while for high to low, it has to be done explicitly like `double` to `int` as in above but only it happened implicitly,why!!!!??

Comment: @NoobEditor It is promoted, while multiplying. But after that it is changed back, according to declaration of n.

Comment: Maybe the update makes it clearer. As i said, change your n to double and everything works fine, because the result doesn't need to be casted anymore

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are interested only in int values:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt(); /**take user input */

if ((n >> 31) == 0) System.out.println("number is positive");
else System.out.println("number is negative");
```

Alternatively for (n >> 31) == 0 you may use (x | 0x80000000) == 0

== UPDATE ==
as mentioned in your comment, you are interested in doubles. Same game:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt(); /** take user input */

if (n * Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) System.out.println("number is negative");
else System.out.println("number is positive");
```

Comment: your answer is smarter than mine. +1

Comment: `int` is easy mate...`double` was troubling me, thankx though, upvoted! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the sign of a number without `<` and `>`, you can read

[Compute the sign of an integer - Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign)

Adapting it to java,

```
public static boolean isPositive(int v) {
 return (((v != 0) ? 1 : 0 )| (v >> (Integer.SIZE - 1))) != -1;
}
```

**Note:** In this example, `0` is considered positive

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to mess with bit arithmetics you could simply use standard Java API [Integer.signum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum%28int%29):

```
int signum = Integer.signum(n);
if (signum == 0)
  //n is 0
else if (signum == -1)
  //n is negative
else //(signum == 1)
  //n is positive
```